# How to load db file using room in android

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I am developing an android app.
I created a ".db" file.

I want to use this db file as the database of my android app.
I am using the Room.
I tried to find any solution, but I cannot find.

```
@Database(entities = [Item::class], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(ObjectConverter::class)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun itemDao(): ItemDao

    companion object {

        private const val DATABASE_NAME = "my.db"

        private var INSTANCE: MyDatabase? = null

        private val lock = Any()

        fun getInstance(context: Context): MyDatabase {
            synchronized(lock) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    initDatabase(context, DATABASE_NAME)
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                            MyDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
                            .addCallback(object : Callback() {
                            })
                            .build()
                }
                return INSTANCE!!
            }
        }

        private fun initDatabase(context: Context, databaseName: String) {
            val dbPath = context.getDatabasePath(databaseName)
            if (dbPath.exists()) {
                return
            }

            dbPath.parentFile.mkdirs()
            val reader = BufferedReader(context.assets.open(databaseName).reader())
            val writer = FileWriter(dbPath)

            var line: String?
            do {
                line = reader.use { readLine() }
                if (line == null)
                    break

                writer.use { it.write(line) }
            } while (true)
            writer.flush()
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to upper code, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate the x.db file [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)
2. Put `x.db` file into the `assets/databases` folder
3. Download files from [this repo](https://github.com/albertogiunta/sqliteAsset)
4. Put those files in a package `sqlAssets`
5. In your `MyDatabase` Class, build `RoomDB` like this :

   ```
   Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), MyDatabase.class, x.db")
   .openHelperFactory(new AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory())
   .allowMainThreadQueries()
   .build();
   ```

P.S : You are using Kotlin. This is Java Code. I don't know the Kotlin yet.

Comment: Should I use the external library?

Comment: Not a library. Just few helper classes. Download from the link I gave. All credits to that guy. :)